# Doob-Meyer decomposition for inequalities

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a family of probability measures $\mathcal{P}$ such that the processes
\begin{equation}
X_t:=ess\inf_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[ B|\mathcal{F}_t],
\end{equation}
is a $\mathbb{P}$-submartingales for any $\mathcal{P}$, nonnegative r.v. $B$, and the  Doob-Meyer decomposition
\begin{equation}
X_t=M_t(B)+A_s(B):=\inf_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[B]+\int_0^t\psi_s(B)dW_s^{\nu}+A_s(B):
\end{equation}
where the increasing process $A$ does NOT depend of $\nu$. My question is if the next reasoning is correct: Define $C=B+1$, then
\begin{align}
    Y_t:&=ess\inf_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[ C|\mathcal{F}_t]\\
&= ess\inf_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[ B|\mathcal{F}_t]+1\\
&=M_t(B)+A_(B)+1
\end{align}
In the other hand $Y_t=M_t(C)+A(C)_t$. By the uniqueness of the Doob-Meyer decomposition I conclude that $M(C)=M(B)+1$ and $A(B)=A(C)$. Is this true? Or there is some trouble that I am not taking into account?. Any help or advicce is welcome. Thank you!